# Windows 10 isn't responding after startup

Tags: windows

I have a GIGABYTE desktop that came with windows 10, it has intel core i7 and 8 gb ram. I was trying to create a new folder but the computer became unresponsive so after a while I restarted it, but when I put the password the desktop came with no icons and the taskbar showing the busy mouse pointer.The taskmanger is not opening neither with CTRL + SHIFT + ESC nor with ALT + CTRL + DELETE. This happens also in safe mode, and running startup repair wont solve the problem no recent backups made and no system restore points. I can only enter safe mode with command prompt.
I can fix this problem without formating my pc
note: I used ubuntu live cd to take all my files

Comment: Delete that folder which you created last and reboot.

Comment: it wasn't created

Comment: How much time did you wait? Do you install any app recently? Do you defrag HDD recently? Does windows explorer open in safe mode without any problem?